# ApexMocks, Test.createStub and System.TypeException @Override specified for non-overriding method

Tags: fflib, stubapi

Simple use case for ApexMocks of a Service layer class, something I've done a 100 times

```
fflib_ApexMocks mocks = new fflib_ApexMocks();

OpportunitiesServiceImpl mockOpportunitiesService = (OpportunitiesServiceImpl) mocks.mock(OpportunitiesServiceImpl.class);
```

At runtime, I get this error:

```
Class.System.Test.createStub: line 93, column 1
Class.fflib_ApexMocks.mock: line 67, column 1
Class.MyTest.myTestMethod: line 28, column 1
System.TypeException: @Override specified for non-overriding method: 
  String OpportunitiesServiceImpl__sfdc_ApexStub.someMethod(Id)
```

The `OpportunitiesServiceImpl` class looks like this:

```
public virtual with sharing class OpportunitiesServiceImpl implements IOpportunitiesService {

  public virtual void method1() {..}
  public virtual void method2() {..}
  private Id doStuff();
  Id someMethod(Id oppoId);
  public class SomeInner{..}
  public virtual void method3() {..} 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the following:

- `OpportunitiesServiceImpl` is at V48.0
- `fflib_ApexMocks` is at V39 (this issues the call to `System.Test.createStub`)

So, I can't explain why this fixes the issue but it does:

The offending method indicated in the error message does not have an annotation of either `public` or `private`. Adding `private` and rerunning eliminates the error

```
public virtual with sharing class OpportunitiesServiceImpl implements IOpportunitiesService {

  public virtual void method1() {..}
  public virtual void method2() {..}
  private Id doStuff();
  private Id someMethod(Id oppoId);  // added the access modifier "private"
  public class SomeInner{..}
  public virtual void method3() {..} 
}
```

*Note that helper methods used by your mocked method must have an access modifier*

Comment: This is strange, I will try this approach

Comment: I believe you must set method as public if you want to mock it, otherwise your mock wouldn't work but the actual method will be called instead of the mock

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to mock a method within a class, like calling some mock for `someMethod` instead of actual method `someMethod` in `OpportunitiesServiceImpl` implementation

```
OpportunitiesServiceImpl mockOpportunitiesService = (OpportunitiesServiceImpl) mocks.mock(OpportunitiesServiceImpl.class);
mockOpportunitiesService.someMethod('005000111222333');
```

you have to make that method public

```
public virtual with sharing class OpportunitiesServiceImpl implements IOpportunitiesService {

  public virtual void method1() {..}
  public virtual void method2() {..}
  private Id doStuff();
  public Id someMethod(Id oppoId);  // added the access modifier "private"
  public class SomeInner{..}
  public virtual void method3() {..} 
}
```

If this method lacks either annotation, then exception `System.TypeException: @Override specified for non-overriding method:`  will be raised.

If this method has `private` annotation, the method will not be mocked, but the actual method from `OpportunitiesServiceImpl` will be called.

So to mock the method, it should have `public` or `global` annotation, in this case the mock will be called instead of the actual method from the underlying class.

Comment: true but even for methods you don't want to mock, all methods in the mocked class need to have private or public annotation; absence of annotation means you get the error described in the OP