# ApexMocks, Test.createStub and System.TypeException @Override specified for non-overriding method: java.lang.Exception

Tags: apex

I recently ran into an issue while mocking (using fflib_apex_mocks...which delegates to Test.createStub(...))  a simple Apex class which implemented an interface. The interface contains a few methods with System.Exception as an argument.
When i attempt to mock the Apex class i get the following error:

> System.TypeException: @Override specified for non-overriding method:
> void RT_TestMock__sfdc_ApexStub.doSomething(String,
> java.lang.Exception) (System Code)

If i use a different argument other than System.Exception, i don't get this error.

Here is the interface:

```
    public interface RT_ITestMock {
    void doSomething(String s, Exception ex);
}
```

Here is the class:

```
    public class RT_TestMock implements RT_ITestMock {

    public void doSomething(String s, Exception ex) {
    }

}
```

Here is the test class:

```
@IsTest
private class RT_TestMockTest {

    @IsTest
    private static void testDoSomething() {
        fflib_ApexMocks mocks = new fflib_ApexMocks();
        RT_ITestMock testMock = (RT_ITestMock) mocks.mock(RT_TestMock.class);
    }
}
```

Running the test class i get the following error:

> System.TypeException: @Override specified for non-overriding method:
> void RT_TestMock__sfdc_ApexStub.doSomething(String,
> java.lang.Exception) (System Code) Class.fflib_ApexMocks.mock: line
> 67, column 1 Class.RT_TestMockTest.testDoSomething: line 10, column 1

If you change the interface and class to pass some other object other than Exception, then i don't get the error.

If i extend Exception and pass in the subclass instead of Exception...i don't get the error.

So it seems it has something to do with mocking a method with System.Exception as an argument.

What am i missing?

Comment: [related (not directly your issue but indicative of some limitations) q&a](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/308928/apexmocks-test-createstub-and-system-typeexception-override-specified-for-non)

Comment: Yes...thank you...i read that article before i posted...the only thing that is common is the error message. I'm not subclassing anything. I'm simply mocking a class with a method containing System.Exception. Interface methods are public by default.

Comment: you might try posting this as an issue on the apexmocks GitHub as well.  Can you work around this by making the 2nd argument to `doSomething` be an object with a member variable of type `System.Exception`?

Comment: Yes...there are a few work arounds...however, the problem is if we create any service or utility with an interface that has an Exception...then it cannot be mocked. This makes for kludgy workarounds in the code. This is not an issue with apex mocks...it's an issue with Salesforce Test.createStub(...) dealing with System.Exception

Comment: have you filed a support case?